# Kubernetes: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (110) - network policy

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

So, I have a Kubernetes pod that executes a script. This script tries to connect to a MySQL server, but I get the message `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (110)`. Every traffic in the subnet that contains the addressed IP is prevented. That's why I set up a network policy (type: Egress), but it still doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: where are you binding your database (bind-address), in `my.cnf`?

Comment: think so, I'm not the admin of the MySQL server :D @suren

Comment: you got to check on that. You might be binding it to the localhost. Try connecting from the localhost (if you can). If you succeed, that's the issue.

Comment: Have you checked in my.cnf where had you binded your database ?